# Get User facebook user detail using cURL

Tags: facebook, curl, authentication

I want to get facebook user Details using cURL in PHP.
i use cURL but they can not give user detail cURL return the redirected facebook URL.
Suggest me for getting details of facebook user using cURL.

Thanks.

Comment: What type of information do you need from the user ?

Comment: Actually i want whole user detail (or facebook page information) without open facebook page. And Update information using facebook account owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get only limited information (public informations) about the user without any access permission. To get that informations using curl, you can try the below code

```
<?php
  $fb_user_name = 'AbdulAzeez86 ';
  $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$fb_user_name;
  $curl = curl_init($url);    
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
  $result = curl_exec($curl);  
  curl_close($curl);  
  $details = json_decode($result,true);
  print_r($details);
?>
```

Here you can change the $fb_user_name with any fb_user_name or user_id .
If you want to get more details then story is different, you need to create an facebook application and get the appropriate access token and use graph api to get the details

Comment: Actually i want to authenticate user and get user details and then update that particular information.

Comment: then  create Facebook application.

Comment: i already created facebook application and i have app_id and app_secret.

Comment: provide us the code which you have tried, then only we can help you. other wise how we know what is the problem in the code